# Local Maven Repository

Tags: java, maven

While working with Maven repository, I understand that Jars gets downloaded at .m2 repository in the hard disk. I want to give it a customized name at my desired location, say "C:\Users\Vamee\Desktop". I read somewhere that I should make changes in settings.xml like below

{M2_HOME}\conf\settings.xml

/path/to/local/repo

C:\Users\Vamee\Desktop

But problem is that I am unable to find Settings.xml in my file system. Please tell me where is Settings.xml or is there any other way to do it.

Comment: Are you trying to change the location of your local Maven repo? My suggestion is: **don't** - Maven runs on the idea of conventions and defaults, the less of them you touch the better. If you need a repo accessible somewhere visible, create a new one, and add it to either your `pom.xml` or `settings.xml`. (When you find it, but `M2_HOME` should be the `.m2` folder in your home folder.) The setting to change the local repository is meant for running a build server where users can `ssh` into.

Comment: I have made a test project using Maven in eclipse. I have not installed Maven on my system. 
1. Does this mean that Eclipse (Kepler) uses its own Maven feature internally ? 
2. If point above is true then it creates .m2 folder in "C:User/Vamee/.m2" path. Am I right ?
3. At above path, I cannot find any settings.xml.

Comment: If the file is missing, Maven just uses defaults for everything. A Maven installation should contain an extensively commented example file in it - just download Maven from the website and poke around the archive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to find Maven installation directory in your file system you will certainly find settings.xml in its conf folder.

Comment: I have made a test project using Maven in eclipse. I have not installed Maven on my system. 
1. Does this mean that Eclipse (Kepler) uses its own Maven feature internally ? 
2. If point above is true then it creates .m2 folder in "C:User/Vamee/.m2" path. Am I right ?
3. At above path, I cannot find any settings.xml.

Answer (score 3):

the environment variable `M2_HOME` should point to the Maven installation directory.

```
e.g. if Maven is installed into C:\Program Files\Maven
set M2_HOME=C:\Program Files\Maven
dir "%M2_HOME%\conf\settings.xml"
```

In the settings.xml you can set the path to your local maven repository.

```
<localRepository>x:/your/local/repository</localRepository>
```

Comment: I have made a test project using Maven in eclipse. I have not installed Maven on my system. 
1. Does this mean that Eclipse (Kepler) uses its own Maven feature internally ? 
2. If point above is true then it creates .m2 folder in "C:User/Vamee/.m2" path. Am I right ?
3. At above path, I cannot find any settings.xml.

Comment: If you are using the embedded Maven in Eclipse your point 2. is right. The settings.xml needs to be created manually and will override the default settings. You need to insert the settings you want to change. Have a look for the file structure and possible sttings here [Maven - Settings Reference](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is in your %USERPROFILE% folder, usually `c:\users\yourname\.m2`

Comment: I have made a test project using Maven in eclipse. I have not installed Maven on my system. 
1. Does this mean that Eclipse (Kepler) uses its own Maven feature internally ? 
2. If point above is true then it creates .m2 folder in "C:User/Vamee/.m2" path. Am I right ?
3. At above path, I cannot find any settings.xml.

Comment: For eclipse, you can find the settings file using the eclipse preferences. Look into Preferences for Maven/User Settings. There is the path to the settings.xml with a button to open it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the operating system, but basically it is in the `.m2` folder your home directory. Or in the `conf` folder in $M2_HOME. See [here](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html).

So it sounds for you like it should be in `C:\Users\Vamee\.m2`.

Comment: I have made a test project using Maven in eclipse. I have not installed Maven on my system. 
1. Does this mean that Eclipse (Kepler) uses its own Maven feature internally ? 
2. If point above is true then it creates .m2 folder in "C:User/Vamee/.m2" path. Am I right ?
3. At above path, I cannot find any settings.xml.

Comment: I don't know how Eclipse works, so hopefully an Eclipse user can chime in. And I always install Maven myself and point my IDE to it. The fact you haven't installed Maven explains why you have no `settings.xml`. Here are the details on creating your own: http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-settings/settings.html. Also, see here for the two locations the file can be: http://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Answer (score 0):

`settings.xml` may not exist - you have to create it.  Then just modify it as [described here](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in the Kepler version of Eclipse for the inbuilt Maven:

1. Create settings.xml in %USERPROFILE%/.m2
2. Add an entry to the settings.xml defining your desired location of the cache, as per SubOptimal's answer above: x:/your/local/repository
3. In Eclipse go Window->Preferences->Maven->User Settings and make sure that the "User Settings" field is set to the full path of your settings.xml file e.g.: C:\Users\user\.m2\settings.xml
4. The read-only "Local Repository" field should show your newly defined cache location.
5. Hit the "Update Settings" or "Apply" button. That should start the process of updating the Maven cache. It might take quite a while.

Answer (score -1):

The maven local repository is located in the /home/.m2 directory, the folder is probably hidden. So, you'll need to press Ctrl+H to see hidden folders. Try finding the setting file there.

Comment: This answer is incomplete and not concisely correct. It also has been covered in other answers. I am down voting it simply because IMO it doesn't really belong.

Comment: @rwheadon This is what solved my problem and not completely the same as other answers! It might not be your solution, but it's not incorrect!